# Stepanov phase transition in random graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-graphs

Consider the classical random graph model G(n,p), with p=c/n, as proposed by Erd\"os and R\'enyi.

At this scaling, the most prominent feature is arguably the abrupt change of the topology  that the random graph experiences when c passes through the value 1: a giant component containing a positive fraction of the component appears, whose size dominates the one of the second largest component (that then decreases as c is increased). That phenomenon is very well documented indeed.

Now, there is also a phase transition occuring at c=2, uncovered by [Stepanov](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1115027?journalCode=tprbau) in 1970, that is visible at the large deviation level only. This one is much less documented. Quoting Puhalski (2010), ["Stochastic processes in random graphs"](https://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0402183v1),

"If c ≤ 2, the [logarithmic asymptotics of the moment generating function of the number of the connected
components] also yield the LDP for the number of
components, as [Bollob\´as, Grimmett, and Janson](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/papers/USmeanf.pdf) (1996) demonstrate, but not for arbitrary c > 0. This anomaly is caused by a phase transition occurring at c = 2 discovered by Stepanov (1970b), which results, as we show, in the action functional becoming non-convex as c passes through the
value of 2. Moreover, the phase transition turns out to consist in a giant component breaking up."

Does anyone know about that other phase transition (or has a good reference on it)? How does it materialize from a probabilistic point of view?  Would there be a way to bring this "out the realm of exponentially improbable" (quoting Biskup)?